# postgresql copy command delimiter non aphanumeric character

Tags: copy, postgresql-9.1, delimiter, non-alphanumeric

I am facing issue while copying a file which is delimited by §. The database version is 9.1

File content are as below:

> a§b§c
>   1§4§5

Copy command:

```
copy test.test_ingestion (a,b,c) from 'b.csv' CSV HEADER DELIMITER as E'§';
```

> Error : invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xa7

As per my understanding § is a UTF-8 character and encoding of database is set to UTF-8.
So why is it failing to copy file delimited by §.

Answer (score 0):

`0xa7` is the code for `§` in iso-latin-1 so obviously the data stream passed to COPY is encoded in iso-latin-1 rather than UTF-8.

As a solution, you can either set `client_encoding` to LATIN1 in the SQL session importing the contents or convert them to UTF-8 before import.